# How timer scheduler run every 15 minutes interval hourly basis

Tags: java, timer, scheduler

- Hi, I would like to run method interval of every 15 minutes .
  Example: If my application initial server start time example 0:12 it
  won't be call timer scheduler run method.
- so my timer scheduler run method particular interval of every
  hourly 15 minutes like :
  `0:15,0:30,0:45,1:00,1:15,1:30,1:45,2:00,2:15,2:30,2:45,.....etc.`
- Below sample snippet code always run method executed when  initial
  application start please let me know where I have made mistaken?
- As per my requirement I need to implement in Timer-Task Scheduler.

  ```
      private class TimerExample{
      private static Timer timer = new Timer();

      private static Calendar getFirstTime() {
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

          int currentMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

          if (currentMinute < 45) {
              cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
          }
          if (currentMinute < 30) {
              cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
          }
          if (currentMinute < 15) {
              cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
          }
          if (currentMinute >= 45) {
              cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 1);
              cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
          }

          cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

          return cal;
      }

      public static void main(String... args) {
          Calendar firstTaskTime = getFirstTime();
          System.out.println("Task will start at: " + firstTaskTime.getTime());
          timer.schedule(new MyTask(), firstTaskTime.getTime(), 1000 * 60 * 15);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: is the code working. There are multiple ways to achieve any objective. At first glance I can tell you it is not the best practice, but I suppose you are learning java so I encourage you to try and write a cleaner one.

Comment: my requirement need to   run method executed for example from 00:15 ,00:30,00:45,01:00,01:15 ,01:30,01:45..etc but  I don't want to run method when initial start example 01:10 from every 15 minutes executed.